# Chain rule for derivatives and simplification question.

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I am trying to find the derivative of the function $$-\frac 13 (e^x −1)^2  +(e ^x−1)+  \frac 15$$
I can only get as far as:

$$e^x - \frac{ 2(e^x - 1)e^x}{3}.$$

The answer I am looking for is $$-\frac13  (e^x(2e^x-5)).$$ For the life of me I can't see how it is being simplified this way, especially where that -5 is coming from. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Try differentiating a little at a time.  For example, can you differentiate $(e^x-1)^2$?

Comment: I'm having a hard time discerning what's in the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
e^x - \frac{ 2(e^x - 1)e^x}{3}&=e^x\left(1-\frac{2(e^x-1)}{3}\right)\\
&=e^x\left(\frac{3-2e^x+2}{3}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{3}e^x(2e^x-5)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing factoring e^x and then using 3/3 * 1 so that we combine like terms. Thank you Larry. Also thanks for editing my post so the equations looks proper :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From where you got, you can factor out $e^x$:
$$\to e^x[1-\frac 23 (e^x-1)]$$

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks!